# Peer to Peer Network in Go

Tags: networking, network-programming, go, p2p, peer

What's the best place to start when implementing a peer to peer network in Go? And is there any good features in Go that would make implementing a peer to peer network easier?

Comment: Just know this one thing - regardless of language, bypassing firewalls for real decentralized P2P is a real pain. it might look trivial at first, but it's a world of pain. I'd first read about it and other aspects of P2P networking and then continue towards Go :) http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

Comment: What do you mean by peer-to-peer network? What should it do? The question is far to general to give any useful advice.

Comment: I would like make a simple version of a crypto currency like bitcoin as an experiment but I don't want to use the bitcoin code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Channels make handling asynchronous network events in Go easier than many other languages.

You should start by reading [Network programming in Go](http://jan.newmarch.name/go/).

Comment: That Newmarch guide is a great introduction to network programming even if learning Go isn't your objective.

Comment: Go makes handling *concurrent* network events easier. Calling them 'asynchronous' is a common error - Go allows blocking without guilt, and its channels can either be unbuffered (blocking) or buffered (non-blocking).